# Align dropdown elements with absolute position

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create a simple Drop Down box as in Twitter:

https://about.twitter.com/products (Click on the language item).

For this I using the following HTML:

```
<a href="#language">English</a>
<div class="popup" id="language">
  <ul>
    <li>Portuguese</li>
    <li>English</li>
    <li>French</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

EXAMPLE: http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/upIjv.

I would to:

1 - The drop downs to align to their link triggers;

2 - Being able to left align or right align the dropdowns to their triggers.

How can I do this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: You would probably have to restructure the HTML...are you happy with that?

Comment: @Paulie_D, don't get your question here. Did I miss something? happy?

Comment: Added a new answer: http://jsfiddle.net/vwkRN/1/

Answer (score 0):

Apply a class of 'relative' to your triggers (.popup{ position: relative; };) and apply a class of absolute to the dropdowns (.popup ul{ position: absolute; }).
You can then move the drop downs *within* the confines of the triggers using left:, right;, etc.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I tried something similar to that and wasn't able to make it work. Thank You.

Comment: Paulie_D kindly provided an example.
I can of course write you code for you, you might not like my hourly rate though ;)

Answer (score 0):

For the absolute positioning you would need to move the popup divs INSIDE the a tags

```
  <a href="#language">English
  <div class="popup" id="language">
    <ul>
      <li>Portuguese</li>
      <li>English</li>
      <li>French</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </a>
```

then position the `a` tags

```
.wrap a {
  position:relative;
}
```

Then position the pop-ups divs

```
.popup {  
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline;
  display: none;
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
  color: #404040;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0;
  top :100%;
}
```

[**Codepen Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GIHtn)

Comment: Paulie, that didn't work. Click on Account. The drop down does not appear under it ... Am I missing something?

Comment: It works in Chrome for me in the Codepen. Have you re-organised you HTML and updated the CSS as I specified?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a').click(function (event) {
    $('.popup').hide();
    var div = $($(this).attr('href'));
    var position = $(this).position();

    $(div).toggle();
    $(div).css({
        'left': position.left,
        'top': position.top + 20
    })
    return false;
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vwkRN/1/)